# Python file() function

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, compiler-errors

I've been adapting an old piece of code to be Python 3 compliant and I came across this individual script

```py
"""Utility functions for processing images for delivery to Tesseract"""

import os


def image_to_scratch(im, scratch_image_name):
    """Saves image in memory to scratch file.  .bmp format will be read 
        correctly by Tesseract"""
    im.save(scratch_image_name, dpi=(200, 200))


def retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root):
    inf = file(scratch_text_name_root + '.txt')
    text = inf.read()
    inf.close()
    return text


def perform_cleanup(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root):
    """Clean up temporary files from disk"""
    for name in (scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root + '.txt',
                 "tesseract.log"):
        try:
            os.remove(name)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

On the second function, `retrieve_text` the first line fails with:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\anpr.py", line 15, in <module>
    text = image_to_string(Img)
  File "C:\Users\berna\Documents\GitHub\Python-ANPR\pytesser.py", line 35, in image_to_string
    text = util.retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root)
  File "C:\Users\berna\Documents\GitHub\Python-ANPR\util.py", line 10, in retrieve_text
    inf = file(scratch_text_name_root + '.txt')
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Is this a deprecated function or another problem alltogether? Should I be replacing `file()` with something like [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)?

Comment: `file` has been deprecated even in Python 2. You should be using `open`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Python 2, `open` and `file` are mostly equivalent. `file` is the type and `open` is a function with a slightly friendlier name; both take the same arguments and do the same thing when called, but calling `file` to create files is discouraged and trying to do type checks with `isinstance(thing, open)` doesn't work.

In Python 3, the file implementation in the `io` module is the default, and the `file` type in the builtin namespace is gone. `open` still works, and is what you should use.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what the [documentation for `file()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) suggests -

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use `open()` instead of invoking this constructor directly.

You should use `open()` method instead.

Comment: Just replaced it for `inf = open(scratch_text_name_root + '.txt', 'r')`, working nicely now :)